# why abstract class cannot be instantiated ,what is the use of a class which cannot be instantiated

Tags: c#, oop

I know and read about abstract class and interface but one point I never understood is that, what is the use of class which cannot be instantiated.
I can use normal class and virtual method instead of abstract class?
what will happen when I instantiate base class?

Comment: An abstract class cannot be instantiated _directly_, but you can have instances of non-abstract classes that derive from it, and an instance of a derived class ___is___ an instance of the base class as well. You are right, if such instances could not exist, the abstract class would not be useful. Likewise for interfaces, you can have instances of classes (or structs etc.) that implement the interface, and those are instances of the interface as well, and without this possibility the interface would not be useful.

Answer (score 23):

You typically use an abstract class when you have some set of common functionality to be shared between derived classes.  That is, you cannot use an interface because you want to provide some default functionality.

Take a look at the [`System.IO.Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) class.  This class provides some common base functionality, but requires that specific types of streams implement some members in order for it to function.  These members are also tagged `abstract`, which indicates to the compiler and runtime that there is no suitable base-class implementation.  A non-abstract class that derives an abstract class *must* override all inherited abstract members, just like a class that implements an interface must implement all members defined on the interface.

In the stream example, the [`Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx) method is abstract, but the [`ReadByte()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.readbyte.aspx) method is not -- because `ReadByte()` can be implemented in terms of a call to `Read()`.  (Although not optimally, which is why `ReadByte()` is virtual, so that a more efficient implementation can optionally be provided.)  Virtual members are different, because they *do* have an implementation, but can optionally be overridden.  Abstract members have **no** implementation by default, and **must** be overridden.

In other words, methods on an abstract class can use other abstract members on the class, even though they have no implementation!  This is because a derived non-abstract class is *required* to provide an implementation -- an implementation is guaranteed to exist at the point that the method is invoked.  This is analogous to how you can use members of an interface even though the members have no implementation on the interface, because it's guaranteed that an object implementing the interface must implement all of its members.

Subclasses like [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) and [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) override all of the abstract methods to form a concrete class, and they can be instantiated.  However, you are able to store them in a `Stream` reference variable and treat them like a generic "black box" stream.  This allows you to declare a method that accepts a `Stream` object, and you don't have to care what kind of stream it actually is.

```
Stream foo = new Stream();       // Invalid, Stream is abstract.
Stream foo = new MemoryStream(); // Valid.
```

So, now to summarize the answers to the questions you posed in your title.  An abstract class cannot be instantiated because it may contain members that are abstract and have no implementation.  The use of an abstract class is twofold: first, to be subclassed and allow the subclasses to share a common implementation of some members, and second, to allow instances of any objects of subclasses to be used through references to the abstract class.

Comment: i have read the above answer before ,and i know these thing but i want to know why Stream class is created abstract ,why not a normal class

Comment: Stream has some abstract methods, that is, it does not know the specific logic of writing or reading to a file or to memory or whatever; but provides a common 'framework' enabling the specific Stream (file e.g.) to just take care of the specifics

Comment: @user1681166 Because a stream is just a concept.  It's a thing that produces or consumes bytes.  There is no "default implementation" of a stream.  When you read from it, where do the bytes come from?  When you write to it, where do the bytes go?  There are several implementations of streams that are backed by files, memory, or network sockets.  But there is no such thing as "just a plain stream."  It's always some *kind* of stream.  The Stream class implements the stuff that's common across all streams.

Answer (score 1):

Abstract and interfaces enable you to share some common logic but you can't instantiate, directlym any of them

To add to cdhowie answer the most relevant differences between interfaces and abstract classes are:

- Inheriting from an abstract class forces child classes to be compromised with a chain of hierarchy. With interface different classes implementing it are completely loose from each other.
- With abstract classes you can have methods or properties with logic, that is, some code is implemented itself in the abstract class. In interface there is no code or logic thus forcing implementors to write all the logic

Answer (score 0):

Abstract classes are very useful and it's all about design. If, for example, you have an abstract base class called Shape, which has functions such as  'Draw' and 'Move'. You then inherit the Shape class to create a 'Circle' class and 'Square' class.

The inherited classes both have the functions Draw and Move. Move may have functionality in the base class which the child classes use, but draw functionality is handled by each child.

While you then instantiate a Circle and Square, it is meaningless to have just a 'Shape' object.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract class and interface class are language features both offering some compile time rules and some run time rules aiding design. So far instantiating abstract class or interface class goes, its not possible using the compiler for sure, if one were to program using assembly language for C++ or say intermediate language code/byte code for C# or Java it might be possible to instantiate them as well, I am not sure on this point though. Since at run time there is a type object for both abstract class and interface class.

Comment: IL that constructs an object from an abstract class is invalid, and should be rejected by a compliant runtime.  Native code that is able to bypass the runtime's checks will create an object that has null or uninitialized function pointers in the vtable for the abstract members.  This will result in undefined behavior when the abstract members are used.